# find a line based on a pattern, add new columns from another file to that line

Tags: bash, text, sed, awk, grep

I have 2 files that I need to merge based on a given pattern (in this case email address).
I would like to bash to do this with grep/sed if possible. Please explain the answer so my weak brain can handle it.

NEW INFO:  There is NO Field Map.  The files are from 2 different data sources, and will not always be the same in number of lines.  Here is the real world:  When Bob stops renewing his museum membership, he will no longer be listed in file 2.  This is part of a weekly report on Membership status for a large non-profit. File 1 will always grow until the end of the year, file 2 may shrink or grow.

I have gotten the second file to a point where it is always comma delineated, and the first field will always be the email address, like in file 1.

in file 1  there is a line like so:

```
007@some.org,007,/Members/Inactive/Delete,2013-06-07T04:41:56.000Z,Never
```

in file 2, there is a line like so:

```
User 007@some.org:  Forward To:None  Enabled:false  Action:KEEP
```

I wish to add the content from file 2 to file 1 to create file 3 formatted as so:

```
007@some.org,007,/Members/Inactive/Delete,2013-06-07T04:41:56.000Z,Never,Forward to:None,Enabled:false,Action:KEEP
```

the 3 new columns should always add to the end of the line.

Comment: What you are trying to do can be easily handled by join. Just type in "man join" and read the manual. Be sure that the files are sorted.

Comment: what are the field separators for file2?

Comment: No "DOH!" required, there is absolutely no way this can be done with just join.

Comment: @EdMorton: except sorting as I mentioned, what makes you think it cannot be done with join?

Comment: @Codism file2 needs to have it's text transformed into comma-separated fields using some fairly complex RE search/replace logic. That's not anything `join` can or should handle.

Comment: @EdMorton: you are right. I didn't notice the leading word User but I suppose it can be handled by sed.

Comment: It's more than that leading word, there's a lot of parsing required. There's several tools can do the job and you COULD choose to have one of those do the difficult stuff of re-formatting file2 and then do a separate join, but the join's the trivial part so you may as well just do it in the same tool if you can (e.g. with awk).

Comment: Hey all, so I got more info to share, I will edit the orginal.

Comment: You already got answers that don't care how many lines are in the files and rely on file2 NOT being comma-separated and formatted as you originally posted so why are you changing your input format now?

Comment: @EdMorton: that happens all the time in software industry, right?  users don't know what they want to do:)

Comment: Smartest guy in this thread is @glennjackman who just asked the fundamental question and waited for a response while the rest of us were running around making assumptions, writing code, and debating possibilities. Darn it!

Answer (score 1):

First modify file2 with desired format (*comma separated*) using search and replace. Here I am using `perl` to achieve this. `sed` can also be used

```
perl -pe 's/User\s+(\S+):\s+(.*?:\S+)\s+(.*?:\S+)\s+(.*?\S+)/\1,\2,\3,\4/g' file2 > file2_new
```

This will result in:

```
$ cat file2_new
007@some.org,Forward To:None,Enabled:false,Action:KEEP
```

Then just use `join` with separator `,` to join two files

```
join -t , file1 file2_new
```

Output:

```
007@some.org,007,/Members/Inactive/Delete,2013-06-07T04:41:56.000Z,Never,Forward To:None,Enabled:false,Action:KEEP
```

Comment: will join still work if the files are not the same number of lines?

Comment: `join` should work irrespective of number of lines in two files as long as they are **properly sorted**

Comment: trying with join, and always getting error,  seems join not to happy when z.chang comes@some.org after zchang@some.org

Comment: @EvilGenius didn't get you. Can you add this sample in your question so I can try at my end?

Answer (score 1):

With a newer release (for `\s` and `\S` instead of `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]`) of GNU awk (for `gensub()`):

```
$ cat tst2.awk
BEGIN {re="\\S+\\s+([^:]+):\\s+([^:]+:\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+).*"; FS=OFS=","}
NR==FNR {map[gensub(re,"\\1","")] = gensub(re,"\\2,\\3,\\4",""); next}
{print $0, map[$1]}
$
$ cat file1
007@some.org,007,/Members/Inactive/Delete,2013-06-07T04:41:56.000Z,Never
$
$ cat file2
User 007@some.org:  Forward To:None  Enabled:false  Action:KEEP
$
$ awk -f tst2.awk file2 file1
007@some.org,007,/Members/Inactive/Delete,2013-06-07T04:41:56.000Z,Never,Forward To:None,Enabled:false,Action:KEEP
```

or with any modern awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    email = $0
    gsub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+|:.*/,"",email)

    sub(/^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"")

    rec = ""
    while ( match($0,/[^:]+:[^:[:space:]]+/) > 0 ) {
        rec = rec (rec ? OFS : "") substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1)
        sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",$0)
    }

    map[email] = rec
    next
}

{ print $0, map[$1] }
$
$ cat file1
007@some.org,007,/Members/Inactive/Delete,2013-06-07T04:41:56.000Z,Never
$
$ cat file2
User 007@some.org:  Forward To:None  Enabled:false  Action:KEEP
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
007@some.org,007,/Members/Inactive/Delete,2013-06-07T04:41:56.000Z,Never,Forward To:None,Enabled:false,Action:KEEP
```

Answer (score 0):

I previously recommended join in a comment without paying attention to the input and output format. As EdMorton pointed out this cannot be solely done in join even if the input files are sorted. So after some discussion with EdMorton and I actually walked through the problem in detail and here is my current solution, assuming the second file is TAB separated:

```
sed -re 's/^User\s//' -e 's/:/,/' file2 | join -t , file1 - | sed -re 's/\t/,/g' -e 's/,,/,/'
```

The above command works in my cygwin/win7 environment, you may need to play with it a little bit if your shell or file2 separator is different.

Some explanation:

```
sed -re 's/^User\s//' -e 's/:/,/' file2
```

Remove the leading "user" and change the first occurrence of colon to comma, which makes file2 joinable with file2 with comma separator.

```
sed -re 's/\t/,/g' -e 's/,,/,/'
```

Replace the separators with comma, as required by the final format. Because join will add a separator in the output between file1 and file2, we will see a pair of comma without the last replacement.

Here is the output:

[image: join result]

Comment: Would you mind posting the output you get when you run that command? To be honest it seems unlikely that it will produce the output the OP posted so maybe it needs a tweak?

Comment: @EdMorton: if I still missed some format, I will give up:-)

Comment: Thanks for posting the output. I didn't understand how you could be getting that but now I just noticed your stated assumption about file2 being tab-separated. If that were true then that makes sense wrt your script and it would make the posted awk and perl solutions much simpler too - it never occurred to me that that might be the case, it just looks like random white space in the question to me. If that is the case, I wish the OP had clued us in!

Comment: @EdMorton: agree, if file2 is space separated, the script will have to be much more complicated. If you still pick on me, I will remove my upvote on one of your comment;-)

Comment: No picking intended, sorry if it came across that way. I work in an environment where we need to produce equipment that is only allowed to go down for a few seconds every few years and must be literally 99.999% (5-9s) reliable so I can be a tad over-zealous at times!

Comment: @EdMorton: I am just kidding and I won't feel offended;-)

Comment: so I managed to get the files formated the same, join should be working, but fails on any instance where a email like zchang us followed by a z. or z-.